# ¿Cómo puedo hacer comentarios anidados en css?

Tags: css

¿Cómo puedo hacer comentarios anidados en CSS?

ejemplo:

Estoy intentando hacer comentarios anidados en css, es decir desactivar un bloque de texto que tiene comentarios dentro.

```
/*
    ul
        {
          font-size: 110%;
          list-style-type: none;
         /* this is a comment*/
          overflow: hidden;
          /*this is a comment*/
        }
*/
```

bueno ese el codigo

Comment: Por favor modera tu lenguaje en las publicaciones, lee [ask], puedes por ejemplo agregar más contenido como explicar si ese código funciona o que te muestra en pantalla

Answer (score 0):

No se puede hacer en css pero con sass si!

```
/*
    ul
        {
          font-size: 110%;
          list-style-type: none;
          //this is a comment
          overflow: hidden;
          //this is a comment
        }
*/
```

Comment: que es eso de sass?

Comment: Un preprocesador de CSS: https://sass-lang.com/